# Group-valued “skew-symmetric” map with composition property.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $X$ be a set, and $G$ a group.

Consider a map $g:X\times X \to G$ such that for any $x,y\in X$:
$$
g(x,y) = g(y,x)^{-1},
$$

and moreover for any $x,y,z\in X$:
$$
g(x,y)g(y,z) = g(x,z).
$$

Is it always true that there is a map $h:X\to G$ such that for any $x,y\in X$, 
$$
g(x,y) = h(x)h(y)^{-1}\quad ?
$$

Note: I've just asked a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794853/decomposition-of-group-valued-skew-symmetric-map), without the last property.

Comment: choose a $x_0\in X$, set $h(x)=g(x,x_0)$.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks.

Comment: Technically I'd called it group-element-valued, not group-valued.